# Can't set values in 2D matrix (vector of vectors)

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I am having trouble understanding why I can't set values in a 2D matrix (a vector of vectors). If I use C-style loops or iterators it works, but it doesn't work if I use c++ range based loops. Can someone please explain why?

Thanks.

```
struct my_str {
   int value;

   my_str(int v) : value(v) {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   // Initialise with some dummy data (creates a 3 x 2 matrix)
   vector<vector<my_str>> array2D;
   for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
      vector<my_str> tmp;
      for (int j=0; j<2; ++j)
         tmp.push_back( my_str(-999) );
      array2D.push_back(tmp);
   }

   // Now try to replace the values
   int ctr=0;

   // Fails
   for (auto array1D: array2D)
      for (auto it: array1D)
         it.value = (float)++ctr;

   // Fails
   for (auto array1D: array2D)
      for (std::vector<my_str>::iterator it=array1D.begin(); it != array1D.end() ;++it)
         (*it).value = (float)++ctr;

   // Fails
   for (int i=0; i<array2D.size(); i++)
      for (auto array1D: array2D[i])
         array1D.value = (float)++ctr;

   // Works
   for (std::vector<std::vector<my_str>>::iterator array1D=array2D.begin(); array1D != array2D.end() ;++array1D)
      for (std::vector<my_str>::iterator it=array1D->begin(); it != array1D->end() ;++it)
         (*it).value = (float)++ctr;

   // Works
   for (int i=0; i<array2D.size(); i++)
      for (std::vector<my_str>::iterator it=(array2D[i]).begin(); it != (array2D[i]).end() ;++it)
         it->value = (float)++ctr;

   // Works
   for (int i=0; i<array2D.size(); i++)
      for (int j=0; j<(array2D[i]).size(); j++)
         array2D[i][j].value = (float)++ctr;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use references, otherwise you are getting copies.

```
for (auto & array1D: array2D)
          ^
    for (auto & it: array1D)
              ^
```

[`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) doesn't keep `const` or reference in type deduction:

```
int i{0};
const int ci{0};
int & ri = i;
int const & cri = i;
auto a = i;   // int deduced
auto b = ci;  // int deduced
auto c = ri;  // int deduced
auto d = cri; // int deduced
```

and in all case, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are copies of `i` and `ci`. Any modification of these values won't affect the value of `i` or `ci`. Whereas

```
auto & e = i; // int & deduced
e = 1; // i is modified
```

Same rule applies here in your for-range loops.

Answer (score 1):

By default `auto` deduces the [*value*](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/value-semantics/) type of an expression. In a range based for loop, this is bad news for class types since each element will be a **copy** of the original element in the container.

Given

```
for (auto array1D : array2D)
```

The compiler fills in the blanks as such -

```
for (vector<my_str> array1D : array2D)
```

Why is a copy used? [According to the standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Explanation), `array1D` behind the scenes would look something like this.

```
std::vector<my_str>::iterator it = array2D.begin();

// this for loop advances the iterator
for (...)
{
    // this is a copy of the element!
    vector<my_str> array1D = *it;
}
```

This "Fails" to work, because when you assign a value to the elements in the second for loop, you will be assigning to a copied vector. This won't modify the original element within `array2D`.

To avoid using copies, let the compiler know that you want `array1D` to be a reference to an element within `array2D`.

```
for (auto &array1D : array2D)
```